# Onkeypress highlight option in drop down box

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

You know when you are entering your personal information on a form, and you get to the state drop down box, most of the time you can type I and it will go right to the states that begin with I.

I am wanting to do the same thing here. My drop down box displays a list of options for a user to choose from. If they want to choose an option that starts with B I would like them to be able to type B and it will bring up the first option that starts with a B hopefully this is clear.

Here is the code

```
$sql = "SELECT iro_option, iro_desc from incrateopt 
                WHERE iro_div = ".$divnmbr."

                AND iro_option NOT IN (
                SELECT cm_optnum
                FROM cmopt
                WHERE cm_serialno = '".$serialno."'
                )
                AND CHAR_LENGTH(iro_desc) > 0
                ORDER BY iro_desc ASC";
         $result=$link->query($sql);
        echo $link->error;

        $ct = 1;
        while($r=$result->fetch_array()):
        $opnum = $r["iro_option"];
        $opdesc = $r["iro_desc"];

        $opdata[$ct] = $opnum." ".$opdesc;
        $ct++;
        endwhile;

        $usearray = "opdata";

        ?>
        <div style="font-weight: heavy;">

        <tr>
           <td>
            <select name="Oparr" multiple size=7 valign=top STYLE="width: 500px;" <? echo $Oparr; ?>>
            <?
             foreach ($$usearray as $value):
                      echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>\n";
                   endforeach;
            ?>
            </select>

           </td>
        </tr>
```

I would imagine that you would do it in the select name some kinda of onkeypress function.

THANKS STACK!

Comment: Check out the chosen plugin using jquery at http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Why are you giving us php code, i think issue is regarding CSS and JS

Comment: Selects already do that. Fill a select with words with different letters and press one of those letters, select jumps to the option automatically.

Comment: Yes my very first option are numbers not the letters. Thanks Jose Manuel Abarca Rodriguez.